# Cucumber, a method that will be called always? Selenium-webdriver.

Tags: selenium, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I am writing tests using selenium webdriver with cucumber. The web page is very much ajax-based. What I want to do is, whenever cucumber calls a method, it should call someother method ALWAYS.

So say in my feature file I have:

When I say hello

which calls method

sayHello()

after this I want

waitForAjax()

to be called.

How can I do this?

Comment: What about using Capybara? It contains autowaiting

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Waiting was just an example.. It may as well be something like logText.. takescreenshot..

Comment: What exactly do you want? I don't understand your qestion. What is in .feature file?

Comment: say i have a method called logWhatHappened().. which prints something on the console.. For examle CurrentTime... So that I can know when exactly that method is called.. I want to call this method everytime cucumber calls something.

Comment: Do you want to invoke that method after each cucumber step or after each invocation of `sayHello`?

Comment: After each cucumber step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke that method after each Cucumber step, you can use AfterStep hook:

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  # Do something after each step.
end
```

Comment: Thanks, where should I put these 3 lines?

Comment: @KorayTugay E.g. to `env.rb`

Comment: what is env.rb? I am using Java.

Comment: @KorayTugay I haven't known that. When one says Cucumber, I think about Cucumber-Ruby. AFAIK Cucumber-JVM doesn't have AfterStep, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/hpYTCKkQhqw)